# unable to use PIL in django view function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a function that makes thumbnail of an image but I am unable to open the image file.

```
def create_thumbnail(request):
    slug = 'yftguhjkn'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if post:
        markdownify = import_string(MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWNIFY_FUNCTION)
        content = BeautifulSoup(markdownify(post.content), "html5lib")
        try:
            img_link = content.findAll('img')[0].get('src')
            print(img_link)
            filename = img_link.split('/')[-1]
            filename = filename.split('.')[0]
            file_path = settings.MEDIA_URL + settings.DRACEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH + post.author.username + '/' + filename + '.jpg'
            print (file_path)
            #im = Image.open(img_link)
            im = Image.open(file_path)
            print (im.size)
        except:
            img_link = 'http://howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg'
        return HttpResponse(img_link)
```

But it is going to except statement. Can someone please tell me how to fix it.

```
def create_thumbnail(request):
    slug = 'yftguhjkn'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if post:
        markdownify = import_string(MARKDOWNX_MARKDOWNIFY_FUNCTION)
        content = BeautifulSoup(markdownify(post.content), "html5lib")
        #try:
        img_link = content.findAll('img')[0].get('src')
        print(img_link)
        filename = img_link.split('/')[-1]
        filename = filename.split('.')[0]
        file_path = settings.MEDIA_URL + settings.DRACEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH + post.author.username + '/' + filename + '.jpg'
        print (file_path)
        im = Image.open(file_path)
        print (im.size)
        #except:
            #img_link = 'http://howtorecordpodcasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/YouTube-Background-Pop-4.jpg'
        return HttpResponse(file_path)
```

Comment: Can you remove the try, except and post the output error message?

Comment: FileNotFoundError at /settings/thumbnail/

Answer (score 0):

I think the **Pillow** need a correct path *(full path)* from the image to open.

```
im = Image.open(file_path)
```

the commond output of `settings.MEDIA_URL` is `/media/` right?
so, you need to `file_path` is the full path, eg:

```
/home/myuser/myenv/myproject/media/images/uploads/2017/05/29/foobar.png
```

If your `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` is:

```
/home/myuser/myenv/myproject/media
```

You can doing with:

```
os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.DRACEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH, image_name)
# example:
'/home/myuser/myenv/myproject/media' + 'images/uploads/2017/05/29/' + 'foobar.png'
```

you can also using `BASE_DIR` for absolute dir.

Comment: it says FileNotFoundError at /settings/thumbnail/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/articles/vasupal/e97e0059af-vasu_photo.jpg'

Comment: how to do that??

Comment: update your post with your current views.. `def create_thumbnail(request):` after _"..tell me how to fix it."_

Comment: please tell me how to fix it